# DataTable: swich 2 Columns without header

Tags: c#, wpf

My Goal is to switch 2 Columns like this:

```
datatable.Columns["column1"].SetOrdinal(1);
datatable.Columns["column2"].SetOrdinal(0);
```

Now what i'm trying to achieve, is that the column header(column1, column2) stay at their place not like the other values.

Comment: The column names/ordinal should stay same but the values in the DataRows should switch the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the row-field order:

```
foreach(DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
{
    object oldCol2 = row["column2"];
    row["column2"] = row["column1"];
    row["column1"] = oldCol2;
}
```

But note that both columns should have the same type.